# Change 5 stars rating to 10 star rating in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, product, review, ratings

I want to change how many stars a product rating is out of? Obviously the **default is out of 5**, I would like to **change it to 10.**

I want this so that I can output '`half stars'` on five stars in the review details for individual rating.

any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add in `rating_option` table but from it may get conflict with already exiting customer ratings and reviews.
fields are : `option_id rating_id, code, value, position`

If you want to install fresh magento script then in set up file.

```
magento\app\code\core\Mage\Rating\data\rating_setup
```

You will find for loop in it change it to your digit.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i ++) {
        $optionData[] = array(
            'rating_id' => $ratingId,
            'code'      => (string)$i,
            'value'     => $i,
            'position'  => $i
        );
    }
```

But this only works at the time of module installation. 
You need to change this before set up magento.

Comment: thank you for your answer and time, but i solved the problem already.

Comment: great sounds fine.

Answer (score 4):

Well, **there are plenty of extensions out there for star rating** (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=star+rating&pl=0). Did you had a look if one of them matches your needs?

If not editing the star rating in vanilla Magento is achieved by modifying the respective files.

This might be a little harder since you also need to persist these values. Thus, I suggest that you search for an existing extension that might just do the trick or at least gives you the head start you might need.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to make change in core to make this happen, I know that is a bad practice, but i want to do this change in core due to some reason.